# In Philip K. Dick's "Time out of Joint", which assertions of Mrs McFee's were correct?

Tags: philip-k-dick

Ragle considered that Mrs McFee's assertions were a "garble of suspicions and rumors", but when she mentioned the word "aluminide", and Mr Gumm later reflected on this by saying "aluminum", Vic appeared to correct him by using Mrs McFee's term of "aluminide" rather than Ragle's "aluminum", hinting to the reader that Vic privately thought that Mrs McFee was more correct about aspects of Ragle's affairs than Ragle himself.

And so my question is, what assertions of Mrs McFee's were correct, and why?

Comment: I've not read this book, but in most  Philip K. Dick books it's impossible to state definitively what is 'correct", and even if you were the "correct" reality might be different in a different part of the book.

Comment: I see what you mean.  It's as if he has intentionally made it impossible for the reader to be sure.  Do you know what motivated PKD to design his books in this way?  Do you think PKD envisaged that the reader would derive pleasure in appreciating that the world is complex enough to accomodate both a true and a false view, in terms of analysing an aspect of it?

Comment: Your asking for an entire literary analysis of his books.

Comment: PKD's Law: "Reality isn't what you think it is, even when you take PKD's Law into account".

Comment: I see what you mean.  For instance, Garret says "Face it - he's a nut", regarding Ragle's suspicious behavior, but moments later, Garret (w/ Mrs Kesselman) blatantly contradict this stance by escaping from him in a manner to suggest that Ragle's suspicions were correct, and so, Ragle wasn't behaving like "a nut".  Do you think this style of writing is in a sense "cheating" the reader?